# How to attach array into the object

Tags: javascript

I have an object where i am associating nested objects. In few places I want to associate array instead of object. Any help how to achive that.

Ex :

```
{ "Id": "ID1",{
        "Data1" : {
            "myData1" : "myVal1"
        },
        "Data2":[{
            "Dat1" : "val1"
        },{
            "Dat2" : "Val2"
        }]
    }
}
```

So in this case somewhere I am attacahing associate by using this code

```
    `ID1[Data1] = "Data1" : {myData1" : "myVal1"}`
```

Can any body please suggest me how to add array.

Comment: can you fix your object syntax, it's currently giving a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows:

```js
const obj = {};

obj['prop'] = {
  test: 'test'
};


obj['arr'] = [];

obj['arr'].push({
  test: 'test'
});

console.log(obj);
```